# groovyPageRenderer Vs groovyPagesTemplateEngine

Tags: email, grails, background

- I am using Grails version 2.4.4
- I have many templates in my project, I need to send them as e-mail
- they trigger point of this mails are either a background process or a web request
- groovyPagesTemplateEngine does not work with jobs, background process
  and anything else without a webrequest

Can I use PageRenderer instead of groovyPagesTemplateEngine ?
Are there any Limitations of PageRenderer ?

Grails issue which is closed has a comment https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3818

"There are some limitations as to what you can do since there is no request. And all links to others templates, controllers etc. have to be fully qualified. "

I tried this for a background job  LinkToController  it seems to be working ?

I do not understand what will not work with PageRenderer bean?

Comment: Grails issue which is closed has a comment   https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PageRenderer` is what you should use yes, `GroovyPagesTemplateEngine` is more low level and although you can use it, is a more difficult API to work with.

Comment: Yes PageRenderer seems to be good option to use , but my question is in what cases it does not work like TemplateEngine and it's specific to this comment [link](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3818?focusedCommentId=64916&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-64916)